# Arquivos na pasta public utilizando o Laravel 4.2 estão inacessíveis

Tags: php, laravel-4, download, laravel-rotas

Olá,

tenho uma aplicação onde são criados alguns arquivos na pasta **public** do **Laravel 4.2**, envio então um e-mail para o usuário com as URL's para efetuar o download destes arquivos, porém ocorre um erro ao tentar efetuar o download.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inicialmente parece envolver as rotas do Laravel, a questão é, se é necessário criar rotas para cada download que vou disponibilizar? Como posso estar fazendo isso? E se não é necessário, qual configuração devo efetuar para que os arquivos da pasta public possam ser acessados por outros usuários?

Agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é preciso definir as rotas para cada download. Você pode acessar os arquivos estáticos usando o Laravel 4 normalmente.

Você primeiramente deve ter em mente que a raiz de uma aplicação Laravel 4 não está na pasta onde se encontra os arquivos da sua aplicação, mas sim a pasta `public`.

O apontamento do Apache (ou qualquer outro servidor que você use) Deve ser feito para a pasta `public`.

Sendo assim, se você tem um arquivo estático no caminho `public/imagens/0001.png`, você não vai conseguir acessá-lo com `meusite.com.br/public/imagens/0001.png`, pois a pasta `public` é a pasta raiz da aplicação.

O caminho correto no exemplo acima seria: `meusite.com.br/imagens/0001.png`.

Lembre-se: Se sua aplicação Laravel 4 está dentro de uma pasta chamada `meusite` o apontamento do Apache deve ser feito para `meusite/public`.

Uma boa forma de testar se sua aplicação foi configurada corretamente é colocando esse código em `routes.php'

```
dd($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Se exibir o caminho com `public` no final, significa que está com a configuração correta (ou digamos, o padrão do Laravel).

Comment: Realmente passou despercebido a questão da pasta public, agradeço a ajuda, o problema foi solucionado.

Comment: Se precisar de alguma coisa sobre Laravel, pode contar com a gente :p